# Do I need to create read-replica as disaster recovery for Multi-AZ RDS deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, multi-az

I have an AWS RDS instance deployed with Multi-AZ set as true.

As a disaster-management strategy in case the DB fails, is creating a read-replica in another AZ redundant?

If I create the read replica in another region (Outside the VPC), would that be redundant too?

Comment: I think read replica (to serve read-only traffic) is not enough, you will need standby replica or consider Multi-AZ DB cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a disaster-management strategy in case the DB fails, is creating a read-replica in another AZ redundant?

Yes. RDS read-replicas are only for scaling read queries and they do not offer automatic failover.

Comment: Thanks for your help Paolo. What would be an additional disaster-recovery strategy in this case? Is Multi-AZ deployment good enough for production data?

Comment: @somya generally speaking yes, that should be sufficient. It kind of depends on how much/little redundancy you want to have